# How to test core dump creation (createdump) for .NET Core macOS app?

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0, .net-7.0, coredump, clrdump

I have a .NET Core application for which I am enabling minidump as follows:

```
<MonoBundlingExtraArgs>--setenv:COMPlus_DbgEnableMiniDump=1 --setenv:COMPlus_EnableCrashReport=1 --setenv:COMPlus_EnableDumpOnSigTerm=1</MonoBundlingExtraArgs>
```

Now, when I launch my app and then send it a SEGV signal through

```
kill -s SEGV <pid>
```

The app crashes, but I don't see a coredump or a `crashreport.json`. I have also tried force quitting the app, but still don't see a core dump or crash report.

I have also tried creating a simple C library with a method that will create a segfault:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void trigger_crash() {
    int *ptr = NULL;
    *ptr = 42; // This will likely cause a segmentation fault
}
```

Then I build this library to produce a dylib. I then create a C# wrapper around it as follows:

```
public class SigHandler {
    [DllImport("handler", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void trigger_crash(string appName, int length);

    public void TriggerSegfault() {
      trigger_crash()
    }
}
```

I copy over the dylib to the MonoBundle in the build and then I call the above C# `TriggerSegfault` method from the managed code to trigger a segfault on a button click. Still, I don't get any core dumps or crash report.

However, if I just have a simple `Debug.Assert(false, "Some statement")`, I see the coredump and the crash report being created.

Can anyone please help me understand where I am going wrong? And if possible, what is the correct way to test a native crash that will create a coredump? Thanks!